# JTable - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to pass the data and column name to constructor

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, jtable

I want to create a simple table using the JTable wherein the values will come from the multi-array object. But when i try to pass that data object and the array of strings for the column names to the constructor, i get  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The .setValueAt method works on this but i want to populate the table by using array.

here is the constructor part of the class.

```
public Table(){
    super("My Table");

    String[] colName = {"Name","Age","Address"};
    System.out.println("ok");
    Object tableValue[][] = {
        {"Dianne Delos Reyes","17", "Lambakin"},
        {"Maya Fojas", "30", "Dubai"},
        {"Robert Alcantara", "Lambakin"}
    };

    table = new JTable(tableValue,colName);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    add(table);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);
}
```

Any idea why i get such error? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{"Robert Alcantara", "Lambakin"}
```

It contains only `two values` else where you have used `3` values. If it tries to access the `third value` it will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thanks . I didn't notice it. :)

Comment: good catch :-) @DianneKatherineDelosReyes you should consider to accept this answer